# Meteor - returning 2 sets of data with iron router

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I'm currently creating a Meteor app using iron router and am having trouble returning 2 data contexts.

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('account', { 
        path: '/account/:accountId',
    template: 'account',
    data: function(){

    //assigning the data object to self in order to use the 'accountId' route paramter
    var self = this;

        var currentRuns = function(){
            return CmrRuns.find({accountId: self.params.accountId});
        }

        var currerntAccount = function(){
            return CmrAccounts.findOne({accountId: self.params.accountId});
        }

        var current = {runs: currentRuns, account: currentAccount};
        return current;
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to do is grab the account info from the CmrAccounts collection and the runs info from CmrRuns collection.

I'm currently getting "currentAccount is not defined" error.
I've been stuck on this for 2 days now and am at a loss.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong here or is there an alternative way to grab 2 sets of data when routing with iron router?

Comment: Can we see where you subscribe to `CmrRuns` and `CmrAccounts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check your subscriptions.  Can you run that same client side query in the console and get the result you're looking for?

Secondly I would simplify the data method. This should work :

```
data: {
    runs: CmrRuns.find({accountId: this.params.accountId}), 
    account: CmrAccounts.findOne({accountId: this.params.accountId})
  }
```

Note though, that `.map` is deprecated : https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1503 which may be the source of many issues.

I would also highly reccommend moving away from this methodology.  Have a look at [FlowRouter](https://github.com/kadirahq/flow-router) as an alternative.  By handling your subscriptions and data with your templates, it becomes a lot neater, easier to diagnose, maintain and migrate.  Further its much easier to maintain data state between routes, which you're likely to run into when building complex UI's.

Comment: I've removed the functions and followed your code example and all looks well.  I thought I'd dabbled with this structure before but clearly not. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Have you changed the Router.map ?

Comment: Yeah I've removed the Router.map. It's a little late for me to  change to FlowRouter but I'll be using that on future projects definitely. Thanks again

Comment: I'd highly recommend it for other projects going forward, while I was initially resistant to drop Iron router, it really has been a massive win.